# Annotation of the first axes does not show when adding the second axes into Matplotlib Figure

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

y = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=50)
y2 = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=50)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)


dots1, = ax.plot(y, 'r.', picker=True, label='data1')

ax2 = ax.twinx()#Comment out the second axes, the annotation works.
dots2, = ax2.plot(y2, 'g.', picker=True, label='data2')

fig.legend()
anno = ax.annotate('N/A', xy=(0, 0), xytext=(-250, 25),
                   textcoords=('offset pixels'),
                   bbox=dict(boxstyle='round', fc='w', alpha=1),
                   arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='fancy')
)

anno.set_visible(False)

def motion(event):
    x = event.xdata
    y = event.ydata
    v = anno.get_visible()
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        c1, ind1 = dots1.contains(event)
        c2, ind2 = dots2.contains(event)


        if c1 or c2:
            anno.xy = (x, y)
            anno.set_text(f'{x}-{y}')
            anno.set_visible(True)
    if v:
        anno.set_visible(False)
    event.canvas.draw_idle()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', motion)
plt.show()
```

Hi, I am trying to plot two sets of Y values onto two axes. When there is only one axis, 'ax' in the code above, the annotation shows and works properly, but once the second axis is added into the graph, 'ax2' in the code, the annotation does not work anymore.

I tried to debug this and found out that every time 'motion' is called, the event comes with only ax2, which means 'if event.inaxes == ax' will always be False.

What should I do to make 'motion' function to be notified with both ax and ax2?

Thank you.

Comment: I am unsure that i understand your question. But I believe you want annotation `N/A` with both `red & green` data plot right ?

Comment: Sort of, yes. So what I wanted to do is that I wanted to annotate both r and g points when mouse hover the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much experience with this type of graph processing, but I was able to handle the condition for two axes with `in (ax, ax2)`. The other thing I fixed was the parameter for the position of the annotations.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

y = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=50)
y2 = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=50)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax2 = ax.twinx()#Comment out the second axes, the annotation works.
dots1, = ax.plot(y, 'r.', picker=True, label='data1')
dots2, = ax2.plot(y2, 'g.', picker=True, label='data2')

fig.legend()
anno = ax.annotate('N/A', xy=(0, 0), xytext=(15, 15),# update
                   textcoords=('offset pixels'),
                   bbox=dict(boxstyle='round', fc='w', alpha=1),
                   arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='fancy')
)

anno.set_visible(False)

def motion(event):
    x = event.xdata
    y = event.ydata
    v = anno.get_visible()
    if event.inaxes in (ax, ax2): # update
        c1, ind1 = dots1.contains(event)
        c2, ind2 = dots2.contains(event)

        if c1 or c2:
            anno.xy = (x, y)
            anno.set_text(f'{x}-{y}')
            anno.set_visible(True)
    if v:
        anno.set_visible(False)
    event.canvas.draw_idle()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', motion)
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is what I got:
https://postimg.cc/5jRHHTHK. 
https://postimg.cc/dZB46FzC
Not sure why there is a big gap tho. 
BTW:Could not see your picture.

Comment: The graph is a little bit inaccurate. https://postimg.cc/xXnDRjhs

Comment: What do you mean by the big gap you are talking about? Are you referring to the arrows and dot positions? If you mean it is too far apart, then fix it to `xytext=(3,3)`.

Comment: Or you may need this setting.`xytext=(0,0)`

Comment: Hi, if you zoom-in the graph, you can see something like this: https://postimg.cc/5XwKZd94. Not sure what is causing this. Do you have any idea? Is it the same to you? Thx.

Comment: Zoomed in with `xytext=(1,1)` and updated with additional point-clicked images. I was not able to confirm such phenomenon in my environment.

Comment: Did you check the image I added? In my environment, it seems to show the coordinates correctly even when zoomed. I can't be sure, but it may be an environmental problem. Why don't you accept this answer and move on to the next step?

Comment: I am sorry that I could not see the pictures I think it was due to the network stuff, but now I can see the pictures you posted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `plotly` that has built-in `interactive` functionality.

Refer the code below :

```py
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

y = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=50)
y2 = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=50)
x = np.arange(0,len(y))

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y,
                    mode='markers',
                    name='markers1'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y2,
                    mode='markers',
                    name='markers2'))
fig.show()
```

[image: Plotly Plot]